# Unable to connect to a NetGear router

Tags: wireless, networking

I am trying to get wireless working on my computer but I just can't....
I've searched for hours on how to connect to the wireless network -- I don't know if I am doing something wrong, but nothing seems to work.

I watched several videos on how to set my wireless connection. All of them clicked on the wifi connection icon in the right hand corner and it listed wifi connections you could connect to. When I tried that nothing was listed. It just said that my wired network was disconnected.

So I tried to add an internet connection, I filled out the SSID, BSSID, and the MAC Address, etc. I clicked "Apply" and it still isn't connecting.

I don't have any experience with Ubuntu. I would really appreciate a step by step on how to solve this. I'm trying to connect to a netgear router, wirelessly.

Comment: Please, avoid using excessive exclamations and language in a way that seems you are screaming. Be polite, use proper titles to your questions and don't be repetitive, be objective and give us the more technical information you can.

Answer (score 0):

Is your router installed properly? Do you have an ethernet cable running to it from your modem? Also, you might need Ndiswrapper if you're using a wireless adapter. run

```
    sudo apt-get install ndisgtk
```

in the terminal, if you can. You can access the terminal by pressing ctrl+alt+t